# Changing the text color of UILabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, uicolor

I am required to change the text color of the `UILabel` which is contained in the `UITableViewCell` on a button click. I have created a `UIColor object`, which is set to specified color on the button click and called the `UITableView reloadData` method, even then the color is not changing. How should I implement this?

Comment: Can you explain little bit more? Do you want to change the color of all rows? Or a single row?

Comment: I have created a custom UILabel in cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource method of UITableView which gets added as a Subview to the cells contentView when i call UITableView reloaddata method. In my code, i m required to change the color of the text of UILabel/ textcolor of the text which is added to the cell based on the selection of the color.

Comment: Fine. Assuming the button as UIBarButton , which is added to the navigation bar, I would like to know whether you need to change the color of all the labels or a single label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to change the color of all rows in your table. (If you just want to change a single row, you will need its `indexPath`).

Create a `BOOL` variable that keeps track of the color state. In your button click routine, set this value appropriately and do a `[tableView reloadData]`.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to check the variable and set the color **for both states** each time. It is essential that you do it both ways, otherwise the state of the cell will be unpredictable when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the text color of a UITableViewCell, you have to implement the **UITableViewDataSource** delegator function

`-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSINdexPath*)indexPath`

In there, you get the cell with

```
UITableViewCell *tableViewcell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"Cell"];

 if (tableViewCell == nil) 
{
    tableViewCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
}
```

And here you can change the text's color.

BTW: You should accept some answers you get to your questions - that will raise your chances to get answers for future questions ...

Answer (score 0):

Fine, while you add the custom UILabel to the contentView, set  a tag for the UILabel.

```
UILabel *cl = nil;
cl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2000];
if( !cl )
{
    cl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,30)];
    cl.tag = 2000;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cl];
}
if( beforeButtonPressed )
cl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
else if ( afterButtonPressed )
cl.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

I guess the above way would be a solution for your requirement.

Comment: I have also done this only. But, i am getting the following error warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame after i press the button and the text color is also not getting updated. Can you pliz help me?

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource method done the following {UILabel *lblInstructionTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            if(ColorIsSetToBlack)
            {
                lblInstructionTitle.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            }
            else
            {
             lblInstructionTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];}
 [cell.contentview addsubview:lblInstructionTitle];}               
         
ColorIsSetToBlack is a boolean which is set on a button click and after that tableview reloaddata method is called. Can u pliz tel me whether i m doing right or not?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Add the code before returning the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Thnx Gomathi for answering and being so cooperative. But i simply implemented this by creating a global UIColor object(defaultcolor), which i assigned specified color on button click and called uitableview reloaddata method. And also in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, i had assigned the uilabel.textcolor =defaultcolor. So, whenever reloaddata method called the defaultcolor which ever was set in that the text color changed.