# UITableViewCell(s) with default image overwritten with other images upon scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, accessoryview

Oops,I am facing an issue with table view cells having no image,i.e. the cell with default image.Upon scrolling the default image disappears and some image from a cell is appearing on it.I have implemented the suggestion from Mr.Rckoenes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093267/uitableview-icons-duplicated-after-scrolling) .Even then I was unable to fix the issue.Here is my implementation code for understanding:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    ReminderClass *reminderToDisplay = [self.remindersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

    // Now create the cell to display the data
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kHelvetica size:17.0];
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    ......

    if (Image != nil) 
    {
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 3, 70, 63)];
        imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [imageView setImage:Image];
        cell.accessoryView = imageView;
        [imageView release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 3, 70, 63)];
        imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        UIImage *defaultImage = [UIImage imageNamed:kDefaultImage];
        [imageView setImage:defaultImage];
        cell.accessoryView = imageView;
        [imageView release];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = reminderDetailsString;
    return cell;
}
```

Can any one please help me,thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just set `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to `nil` and also `reuseIdentifier` to `nil` like bellow..

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

and

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
```

and also add your other code in this `if (cell == nil)` if condition..

**UPDATE:**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row]; 
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kHelvetica size:17.0];
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:kDateFormat];
    NSDate *reminderDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:reminderToDisplay.Date]; 
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:kMinDateFormat]; 
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:reminderDate];

    NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:kNameEvent,reminderToDisplay.Name,reminderToDisplay.Event];
    NSString *onString = [NSString stringWithFormat:kOn,dateString];
    NSString *reminderDetailsString = [valueString stringByAppendingString:onString];

    ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressbook);
    CFIndex numPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressbook);
    for (int i=0; i < numPeople; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

        NSString *firstName=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

        NSMutableDictionary *contactsDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];

        if(firstName != nil && firstName != NULL)
        {
            [contactsDictionary setObject:firstName forKey:kFirstName];
            CFRelease(firstName);
        }
        else
        {
            [contactsDictionary setObject:@"" forKey:kFirstName];
        }
        if(lastName != nil && lastName != NULL)
        {
            [contactsDictionary setObject:lastName forKey:kLastName];
            CFRelease(lastName);
        }
        else
        {
            [contactsDictionary setObject:@"" forKey:kLastName];
        }

        //Get the first name and last name added to dict and combine it to form contact name
        firstName = [[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[contactsDictionary objectForKey:kFirstName]]autorelease];
        lastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[contactsDictionary objectForKey:kLastName]];
        self.contactName = [firstName stringByAppendingString:lastName];

        //Now check whether the contact name is same as your reminderToDisplay.Name
        if([reminderToDisplay.Name isEqualToString:contactName] && ABPersonHasImageData(person))
        {
            CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
            self.reminderImage = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)imageData];
            CFRelease(imageData);
        }
    }

    CFRelease(allPeople);
    CFRelease(addressbook);

    if ([reminderToDisplay.reminderGroup isEqualToString:kFacebook])
    {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:kImageName,reminderToDisplay.Name];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *reminderString=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:imageName]];
        self.reminderImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:reminderString];
    }

    if (reminderImage != nil) 
    {
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 3, 70, 63)];
        imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [imageView setImage:reminderImage];
        cell.accessoryView = imageView;
        [imageView release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 3, 70, 63)];
        imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        UIImage *defaultImage = [UIImage imageNamed:kDefaultImage];
        [imageView setImage:defaultImage];
        cell.accessoryView = imageView;
        [imageView release];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = reminderDetailsString;
        }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but still it doesn't work,I think it is a problem in assigning reminderImage,actually I am assigning reminderImage based on some conditions and also if it is nil,I am assigning the default image

Comment: no no this type of problem i faced .. its problem with its again load that image when your tableview scroll right?? and for that use above logic otherwise i will upload another logic for that ...

Comment: Can you please proceed with what you said,uploading another logic,I mean I have implemented what you have suggested but still not working my way

Comment: Worked like a magic,thank you Mr.Paras Joshi,up-voted,cheers :)

Comment: To be honest I gave the answer for this kind of issue,i.e. to reuse cell identifier based on index path row and section,strange I didn't implement it which costed me the issue :)

Comment: yes yes dude sometime we forgot something which we create or develop at that required.. but now its working then its fine .. :)

Comment: If you don't mind me taking undue liberty in asking this,I am facing an issue with Facebook post to wall,I don't know whether the code is working or not,I need to post to friends wall on his/her birthday with sdk 3.0.I heard that Facebook has disabled the feature of doing it with request graph path from February.So they suggested me to go with Feed Dialogue,and I also heard that it is not possible to schedule the post,I have just visited your profile and glad to know you are a senior developer.Can you please help me on this sir.Pulling my hair for this since weeks :(

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya yes dude i will post comment on monday and you want to post text on your frinds wall right??

Comment: Link to my question can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503497/post-to-friends-wall-on-scheduled-time-using-facebook-sdk-3-0

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya ok i will see that que and post the answer , i will try to give you the best answer and you get solution from that.. :)