# Duplicate data when scrolling a UITableView with custom subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

This worked before, unless it's been so long I'm overlooking something. When the table first shows everything looks great but if I scroll up and and down labels get duplicate content.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UILabel *labelName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 35)];

        labelName.tag = 20;

        [cell addSubview:labelName];
    }

    ((UILabel *)[tableView viewWithTag:20]).text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Try [cell.contentView addSubview:labelName];

Comment: try to set `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to `nil`, see my answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702242/uitableviewcells-with-default-image-overwritten-with-other-images-upon-scrolli/15702271#15702271

Comment: Wont setting dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to nil create a new cell for every row?

[cell.contentView addSubview:labelName]; has no effect.

Comment: @RyanDetzel yes if you have limited record means not bunch of records then do it otherwise try my bellow answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spotted the line that provokes it!

```
((UILabel *)[tableView viewWithTag:20]).text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You're getting the label by sending `-viewWithTag:` to `tableView` but you should ask the cell.

On a side note it's always better to add subviews to a cell's `contentView`

Here's the right implementation.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UILabel *labelName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 35)];

        labelName.tag = 20;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:labelName];
    }

    ((UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20]).text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Damn, nice catch. I thought everything looked okay it's good to have another set of eyes. Is it normal that cell is nil for new rows? I thought it would reusing the same cell for every row? For example, when the tableview first loads cell is nil for each new row.

Comment: Yes the first cells need to be allocated. Only after they are scrolled out they can be reused.

Comment: Reference to your post answer, Can I ask one question related to this `cell.contentView` please?

Answer (score 1):

write this bellow line inside the `if (cell == nil)` condition

```
labelName.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and comment or remove this bellow line..

```
((UILabel *)[tableView viewWithTag:20]).text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: i know that but if records are not more then it will work perfact and

Comment: "If" Even if he has only little data, there will be lots of people reading this solution after it and it's not a good example on how to use table views.

Comment: With your edit now it would only set the text the first time the cell is allocated. He's already setting the text where he should do it!

Comment: here whats the problem is text is overwrite so this is way to avoid it also when tableview reloaded at that time it call again , and if you know with best answer then please post that answer dude.. :)

Comment: When the table view would be reloaded or only scrolled. The cells would be reused, so dequeued, and not nil. So it would not satisfy the cell == nil condition. Setting the text should be done outside that block!

Comment: I commented the question on what could solve it (adding the label to the contentView) but I'm not sure it would work. That's why I didn't put it as an answer :)

Comment: no its not worked dude but i think this above solution is better now :)