# Wrong Cell Selected in CutomTableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In multiple selection of tableview cell. When I select 1st cell 7th cell is also automatically get selected. I've implemented multiple cell selection functionality. I tried some methods but ain't working.

This is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[mytableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    [def setObject:[model objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"model_%i",counter]];
    [def setObject:[year objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"year_%i",counter]];
    [def setObject:[colorid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"colorid_%i",counter]];
    [def setObject:[vin objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"vin_%i",counter]];
    [def setObject:[price objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"price_%i",counter]];
    [def setObject:[color objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"color_%i",counter]];

    counter++;

    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    [selectedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    [selectedIndexes insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] atIndex:counter];
}
else
{
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    [selectedIndexes removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"model_%i",counter]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"year_%i",counter]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"colorid_%i",counter]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"vin_%i",counter]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"price_%i",counter]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"color_%i",counter]];

    counter--;
}
```

I am using custom tableview cell, I've checked its height also. My cellforRowAtIndexPath method looks like,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell17";

VehicleListCell *cell = (VehicleListCell *)[mytableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VehicleListView" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: check out my answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702242/uitableviewcells-with-default-image-overwritten-with-other-images-upon-scrolli/15702271#15702271

Comment: use my answer from above link otherwise if you have not bunch of data then just set `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to `nil` like this `VehicleListCell *cell = (VehicleListCell *)[mytableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];`

Comment: @ParasJoshi. I've tried but it's not working. Also all tableview cell appear blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
[selectedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
[selectedIndexes insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] atIndex:counter];
```

Here you add the same object twice. That might cause your issue. 
Log `selectedIndexes` to see what is happening.